# Скачивание файла по простой ссылке

Tags: download

Есть сайт site.ru Нужно сделать так, чтобы файл, к примеру 1.rar, который лежит например в public_html, скачивался по простой ссылке, например site.ru/+
Как-то так. Как это лучше всего реализовать, чтобы не нагружать сервер и не замедлять загрузку самого сайта? Советы? Решения?

Comment: вопрос непонятен.

Comment: @DollarDollar так задайте вопрос, что именно вам непонятно.

Comment: Vitalii, про « не нагружать сервер и не замедлять загрузку» — а вы точно не преждевременно оптимизируете? Файл большой и/или загрузок будет много, так что это нагрузит сервер так, что замедлится загрузка страниц сайта?

Comment: @NickVolynkin а это мне надо или кому? да ничего особо непонятно.

Comment: Вопрос такой, на сервере лежит файл, 1.rar Нужно сделать так, чтобы при переходе на ссылку site.ru/1 сразу скачивался файл, и закрывалась вкладка. Все, больше ничего. Как это правильно реализовать, желательно попроще. В архиве ничего личного/важного не будет, просто нужные файлы, которые нужно очень быстро и просто скачивать на других компьютерах. Но если можно это как то скрыть, чтобы не индексировалось и нигде не светилось, то будет очень даже хорошо